# How to view Hazelcast cache logs

Tags: java, docker, jhipster, hazelcast, spring-cache

I have a project with two microservices and a gateway. Both were generated through JHipster. I use Hibernate 2nd level cache for caching and implemented this with [Hazelcast cache](https://www.jhipster.tech/using-cache/) solution. Everything deployed to  Docker using docker-compose. My question is "When I load the entities the second time, **how do I know if microservice hitting the database or fetching from cache**". Where can I see generated hibernate queries for each request? And cache provider logs? Code uploaded to [Github](https://github.com/pavankjadda/Kubernetes-SpringCloudStream-Kafka-Docker) for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach, which can be utilized all the way up to production, is using the [management center application](https://hazelcast.org/download/#management-center).You can monitor put and get throughtput and many other performance statistics of your cluster using the [management center application](https://hazelcast.org/download/#management-center). Alternatively you can use jconsole, or mission control (if using Oracle’s JVM) to connect to each individual node to view JMX stats.